# Convert freq string to DateOffset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas documentation one can read "Under the hood, these frequency strings are being translated into an instance of pandas DateOffset" when speaking of freq string such as "W" or "W-SUN".

Then, how can I get an instance of a DateOffset given a string ? Ultimately want to configure my program with frequency as string (say "W-SUN"), but internally want to do something like

```
offset = Week(weekday=0)
if d1-3*offset<d2:
    pass
```

but defining `offset` from string.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the `to_offset` function for this, although this is a rather internal pandas function (so possibly no backwards compatibility guaranteed). Some examples:

```
In [12]: pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('4Min')
Out[12]: <4 * Minutes>

In [13]: pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('W-SUN')
Out[13]: <Week: weekday=6>
```

Comment: only had to search multiple times across 3 days to find this answer.

Comment: is it possible to add a time to this?