# Convert `pandas` frequency string to `DateOffset`

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dst

I have a timezone-aware `pandas` `DateTimeIndex`, which I would like to advance by one timestep, with the timestep as specified by its `.freq` attribute. However, doing this does not respect the time zone information:

```py
import pandas as pd
i = pd.date_range('2020-03-28', freq='D', periods=3, tz='Europe/Amsterdam')
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-28 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00',
#                '2020-03-30 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='D')

i + i.freq
# Not what I want; second timestamp is advanced by 24h instead of 23h and is no longer at midnight:
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-30 01:00:00+02:00',
#                '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='D')
```

What *does* work is using `pd.DateOffset`:

```py
i + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
# What I want; all timestamps at midnight (I just need to re-set the .freq attribute):
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-30 00:00:00+02:00',
#                '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq=None)
```

However, as I don't know in advance what the frequency of the index will be, **I'd like to use the value of `i.freq` to get the correct `DateOffset`**. Is there a way to do this? (Apart from using a long `if... elif... elif...` block.)

Other solutions also welcome, of course.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368265/convert-freq-string-to-dateoffset-in-pandas) is the only other question related to this that I found, but I cannot use it here:

```py
i + pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(i.freq)
# Not what I want:
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-30 01:00:00+02:00',
#                '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='D')
```

(In fact, the latter term returns exactly `i.freq`.)

Many thanks.

### EDIT (1)

As suggested in the comments, using `.shift(1)` works in some cases, including in my stated case above...

```py
i.shift(1)
# What I want; all timestamps at midnight:
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-30 00:00:00+02:00',
#                '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='D')
```

...but not in all. In fact, advancing the start date in my original index by one day causes a timestamp to get dropped, and the remaining ones are wrong:

```py
i2 = pd.date_range('2020-03-29', freq='D', periods=3, tz='Europe/Amsterdam')
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-30 00:00:00+02:00',
#               '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='D')

i2.shift(1)
# Not what I want: timestamps not at midnight, and one got dropped!
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-30 01:00:00+02:00', '2020-03-31 01:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='D')
```

### EDIT (2)

As suggested in the answer by @MrFruppes, using the `.nanos` attribute of `i.freq` works as input to `pd.DateOffset`...

```
i + pd.DateOffset(nanoseconds=i.freq.nanos)
# What I want; all timestamps at midnight (I just need to re-set the .freq attribute):
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-30 00:00:00+02:00',
#                '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq=None)
```

... but it breaks when we try to advance to the beginning of next month:

```py
i3 = pd.date_range('2020-03-01', freq='MS', periods=3, tz='Europe/Amsterdam')
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-01 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-04-01 00:00:00+02:00',
#                '2020-05-01 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='MS')

i3 + pd.DateOffset(nanoseconds=i3.freq.nanos)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-58-f3a32c654a6e>", line 1, in <module>
    i3 + pd.DateOffset(nanoseconds=i3.freq.nanos)

  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\offsets.pyx", line 690, in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.BaseOffset.nanos.__get__

ValueError: <MonthBegin> is a non-fixed frequency
```

Comment: You might over think the problem. Instead of shifting the index, you might just use `shift` to shift the data.

Comment: Damn. 2 days trying and testing answered in 1 minute. But, it works! Many thanks! :)

Comment: Ah, I found a case where this does not work; I'll append to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.DateOffset` is also not universally working. Here is what I currently have which passes all my unit tests, but I'm open to improvements:

```py
if i.tz is None:
    raise AttributeError("Index is missing timezone information.")

# Get right timestamp for each index value, based on the frequency.
# . This one breaks for 'MS':
# i + pd.DateOffset(nanoseconds=i.freq.nanos)
# . This drops a value at some DST transitions:
# i.shift(1)
# . This one gives wrong value at DST transitions:
# i + i.freq

if i.freq == "15T": # period length always the same
    ts_right = i + pd.Timedelta(hours=0.25)
elif i.freq == "H": # period length always the same
    ts_right = i + pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
else:               # period length dependent on calendar
    if i.freq == "D":
        kwargs = {"days": 1}
    elif i.freq == "MS":
        kwargs = {"months": 1}
    elif i.freq == "QS":
        kwargs = {"months": 3}
    elif i.freq == "AS":
        kwargs = {"years": 1}
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid frequency: {i.freq}.")
    ts_right = i + pd.DateOffset(**kwargs)
```

(I've only implemented the `.freq` values relevant to my use case.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed frequency, you can use the `nanos` property of the freq. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
i = pd.date_range('2020-03-29', freq='D', periods=3, tz='Europe/Amsterdam')
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-30 00:00:00+02:00',
#               '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq='D')

i + pd.DateOffset(nanoseconds=i.freq.nanos)
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-30 00:00:00+02:00', '2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00',
#                '2020-04-01 00:00:00+02:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MrFuppes. It seems to work for `D` frequency... but my unit tests break for `MS` frequency with a `   ValueError: <MonthBegin> is a non-fixed frequency`

Comment: @ElRudi, yep, just scrolled through the [src](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx) and found that out too... anyways, I'll leave the answer in case somebody only has a fixed freq. Or might use it to derive a better solution ;-)